# Squeeze some extra life out of radiator and condenser fans

Tags: maintenance, noise, fan, bearing

Both my radiator and condenser fans are whining, high pitch  and loud, presumably from the bearings although maybe something else is rubbing somewhere. They started around the same time, I think it was triggered by coolant leaking all over them (fixed) plus me squirting them down with a lot of water.

I don't want to replace the units right now. I'm just going to pull them apart and try to clean them up a bit.

So my question is, what kind of love can I give these electric fans to get a little more life out of them before they burn themselves out? And what kind of lubricant should I slop around the bearings? 3-in-1? Some kind of grease? I don't want to do anything that will cause more damage in the long run. I am also thinking I'll clean off any rust or corrosion on shafts and such with a wire brush. What else can I do, any tips or tricks appreciated.

Comment: I think you should put in some pictures just to show what your fans look like.  In the case of my Chevy, there was no way to get to the motor bearings from the outside...

Comment: @Zaid Yeah I thought this question would be generic but... guess not. Thanks for digging up the radiator fan (I'm impressed you remembered what car I had, lol). I'll dig up a compressor fan pic when I'm back at my pc.

Answer (score 3):

I would not try to grease the bearings. Normally a bearing this size is sealed by either a rubber ring (designation suffix 2RS) or a steel sheet ring (designation suffix 2Z), so just slopping some grease on it wont solve the problem. Metal sheet covered bearings are protected against dust but not against moisture, rubber covered ones are protected against moisture but are more expensive and the maximum rpm are somewhat limited.

Manufacturers love the steel covered ones because they are cheaper and the part fails earlier (but most of the time not early enough to be under guarantee).

I have the totally unfounded suspicion that the fans contains each two metal sheet covered deep groove ball bearings in a standard size. I would just try to disassemble the fans, extract the bearings and replace them with some rubber covered quality bearings.

Comment: I think I'm going to try this first (replacing the bearings). We'll see what it looks like when I disassemble them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see that there is much you can do about the squeaking.

Unless you can crack open the electric motor housing, there isn't much to disassemble to get at the motor bearing.

[eBay says](http://www.ebay.com/itm/OEM-1997-2001-Honda-Prelude-Radiator-Fan-Assembly-0050-/231878798252?fits=Year%3A2001%7CMake%3AHonda%7CModel%3APrelude&hash=item35fd0dabac:g:jpIAAOSwr7ZW6Du7&vxp=mtr) this is your radiator fan:

[image: Prelude fan]

There will be a nut that fastens the plastic fan blade (left-handed thread). Removing that will allow you to gain access to the motor itself.

I imagine that what you can do to lubricate the motor shaft will be quite limited though, since it is likely that the squeaky bearing will be inside the motor housing.

From my own experience (Chevrolet Lumina) spraying copious amounts of WD-40 did little to stifle the noise. There wasn't anything else to spray at the time. I ended up replacing the fan motor to solve the problem.

Comment: Oh. And thanks. I haven't actually removed them yet to look at the front, I just assumed they'd be disassemblable. Ah well. I was going to avoid the wd40 because I didn't want to wash any existing grease out. If I can't just replace the bearings, maybe I can drill a hole in the side of the housing and just douse it in 3-in-1 and hope for the best.